# To add data table with Crystal charts

Tags: crystal-reports

i am using Crystal 2008 and Would like to add data table just underneath attached to a Chart. This can be done very easily in Excel. Don't know how to do it in Crystal

please advise....much appreciated

Comment: @admdrew - Crystal Reports questions are on topic here - it's a definitely a little unclear, but a comment literally saying "your question is bad, go read the entire help center" doesn't help terribly much.

Answer (score 0):

The way your question is worded I'm not clear if you mean under as in "behind" or "below".  It would help if you include a mockup drawing of what you're trying to accomplish.

If you mean "behind", the feature you're looking for is Section Underlay.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcxlD2udUcw) gives a small demo of the feature to put a watermark image behind the report, but you can do the same thing with a chart, crosstab, or other object.  The "World Sales Report" sample report has another example of this feature to put a table beside the chart.

If you mean "below", you can either just add sections and put your data fields there, or if that's not the type of table you're looking for, you may want to use a Crosstab object.

Comment: Here is the example attached for my required chart (http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image.png); i would like to create the chart with data attached just below the chart. so i can save some space in the report (show chart with data)

Comment: In the chart image you linked to, it looks like the data table under the chart doubles as the chart legend. CR doesn't have custom legends like this. You can use a crosstab to get a similar effect, but the cells of the crosstab won't necessarily line up with your chart without a lot of futzing around. Just create multiple sections in the area you want the chart in, then put the chart in the top section and the crosstab in the next section.

Comment: Thanks Chris.... yes i had to add a crosstable table just below the chart (spend lot of time to adjust it though). Although it took effort to get what was required but report looks awesome. Thanks again